# Rendering one element on Chrome - cross-browser issue admin-on-rest

Tags: admin-on-rest

I've sent this as an issue because I believed it was at least a documentation problem, but I was advised to sent as a question in here.

I'm using [admin-on-rest](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest) which is working perfectly on Firefox, but not on other browsers.

I've done every step as the documentation suggests, got the newest version so far and tried to search in the opened issues and stack overflow for a similar problem.

It seems to be a problem with cross-browser implementation or documentation with admin-on-rest.

**What is happening:**

The main problem is that for some browsers, mainly Chrome, it works fine until I try to GET_ONE or UPDATE resource. It gets the correct response, tries to render and then gives an **Element does not exist** error, returning to previous page (LIST).

[admin-on-rest Problem Video](https://youtu.be/L2ufzZ1tHew)

**Steps to reproduce:**

I created a fake account so you could test it. If you wish sent me in private and I may share with you.

I open the LIST view for *Scores*, click in *show*:

- Scores -> *show* (any element)

It gives Status code: 200 OK, it renders and fails, going back to the previous page.

**Other information:**

I'm using admin-on-rest with a custom restClient [ restClient={myApiRestClient('http://localhost:3000/v1', httpClient) ], which seems to be fine, seen that the request runs out ok.

**Environment**

- Admin-on-rest version: "^1.3.2"
- React version: "^15.6.2"
- Browser: **Chrome, Chromium** and **Opera**

Answer (score 0):

For `GET_ONE` you may be returning the data directly instead of `{'data': your_data}`.

Instead of:

```
{
  'id': 3,
  'name': 'xyz'
}
```

it has to be returned as

```
{
    'data': {
        'id': 3,
        'name': 'xyz'
    }
}
```